# Como mudar a cor de um link ao passar o rato (mouse)?

Tags: html, css

Tenho um menu horizontal com os links (exemplo): Home; Sobre; Contatos;

A ideia é que o home fique sempre com o padding background verde e o resto dos links com background branco. Quando se passa o rato (mouse) por cima dos demais links o respectivo background mude de cor passando a ser verde (li:hover).

Comment: Vamos lá, David. Edite sua pergunta e explique detalhadamente o que você precisa, o que você já tem pronto e, se possível, use o JSFiddle (agora você sabe como funciona).

Comment: @BrunoAugusto penso que tinha tudo isso. O problema foi de quem editou. Deve ter apagado. Já não me recordo.

Comment: David mesmo sem a edição não se percebe qual é o problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso é bem básico, sugiro que você estude um pouco mais sobre classes, e suas propriedades, um bom lugar para aprender muita coisa é no site [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

De qualquer forma, segue um pequeno exemplo:

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    width: 100px;
    height:36px;
    line-height:36px;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
}
li:hover, .active {
    background-color:#00ff00!important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">Home</li>
    <li>Produtos</li>
    <li>Download</li>
    <li>Contatos</li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/ptux6yh8/)

Comment: brasofilo está quase. A ideia é que home nunca fique sem o verde. Sabe como fazer? Obrigado pela referência.

Comment: @David editei a resposta e o jsfiddle e corrigi para o ativo ficar fixo, particularmente eu acho meio estranho assim...